# C# FileWatcher Get UserName that dropped a file

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I realize that I may have to use Auditing to get the answer here but short of that I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get the name of the User that dropped the file into the watched folder.

Business reason for asking:
We have automated systems that generate various types of support documents.  These often have only the "creator" property set and it is generally either "Administrator" or the Service Account.  At some point after generation, a user has to manually decide that the file is good enough to be forwarded on and it is dropped into a folder on the network.  Being able to capture that name in a passive way (like through a Filesystem Watcher) could be helpful in our pursuit of process improvement.

Is there a method to capture who is dropping a file into a watched folder?
Note: our environment is full stack Microsoft and 64-bit.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-8.0) to see what information is available? I don't see anything that indicates who made the change.

Comment: That is where I started.  I also went through any of the options in Shell.  The only thing I found that could work deals with capturing the underlying permissions structures and Windows messages which is WAY more exotic than the need warrants.  It would be simpler to block standard browsing to the folder and then distribute an icon across the relevant portion of the enterprise that when a file is dropped on it it sends the file and updates a designated file attribute.  This still feels a bit exotic but it is an option that can be pushed to those authorized to alter processes.